# How do I regex search for weird non-ASCII characters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, ascii

I'm using the following regular expression basically to search for and delete these characters.

```
invalid_unicode = re.compile(ur'(Û|²|°|±|É|¹|Í)')
```

My source code in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoded, and whenever I try to run the script it spits out:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xdb' in file ./release.py on line 273, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

If I follow the instructions at the given website, and place `utf-8` on the second line encoding, my script doesn't run. Instead it gives me this error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 0: unexpected end of data

How do I get this one regular expression running in an ASCII written script that'd be great.

Comment: I just figured out that these characters, aren't unicode but extended ascii code.

Comment: I highly recommend reading Joel's article on Unicode and character sets: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find out what encoding your editor is using, and set that per PEP263; or, make things more stable and portable (though alas perhaps a bit less readable) and use escape sequences in your string literal, i.e., use `u'(\xdb|\xb2|\xb0|\xb1|\xc9|\xb9|\xcd)'` as the parameter to the `re.compile` call.

Comment: I wouldn't use the byte representation of an Unicode char as it's really locale dependent. I'd escape as Unicode, and thus avoiding any complication.

Comment: @Paulo, Unicode encodings are **not** necessarily locale-dependent -- you can use `'utf-8'` or other locale-independent encodings. But in any case, the form I give above is what a `print repr(thestring)` emits, does **not** rely on any encoding, and cannot possibly cause any complications (it's just the same as using `\u00db` and so on, guaranteed to produce absolutely identical Unicode objects, just more concise as it saves you typing the unchanging `00` parts!-).

Answer (score 1):

After telling Python that your source file uses UTF-8 encoding, did you actually make sure that your editor is *saving* the file using UTF-8 encoding? The error you get indicates that your editor is probably not using UTF-8.

What text editor are you using?

Comment: Here's how to configure UTF-8 in Notepad++: http://superuser.com/questions/21135/how-can-i-edit-unicode-text-in-notepad

Answer (score 0):

```
\x{c0de}
```

In a regex will match the Unicode character at code point `c0de`.

Python uses PCRE, right? (If it doesn't, it's probably `\uC0DE` instead...)